# Fastest way to find duplicates in a string without using any additional memory in java?

Tags: java, string

What is the fastest way to remove duplicate character in a string without using an extra memory in Java?

Comment: I will be more than willing to help if you put some examples.

Comment: Examples aren't really needed, this is a question about the internal processes of structures relating to strings.

Comment: Given that strings are immutable in Java, you're going to at least need "extra memory" for the new string with the characters removed. It would be good if you clarified what you mean by "extra memory". Also, keep in mind that frequently there is a trade-off between memory usage and speed.

Comment: Throwing this little trivia out there: String.substring uses the original string as a backing so... (and now back to reality)

Comment: Do you know the duplicate character ahead of time, or do you find all the duplicates then remove them?

Comment: @pst: It still creates a String object to encapsulate the new offset and/or length... and the fact that it does is an implementation detail so there is no guarantee than any given implementation with do it (a) ever, or (b) always. In fact, a really good JVM implementation might spot the fact that there are only small substrings to a really large string remaining and rebuild them under the hood. The point is you don't know what the implementation might do while still honoring the public contract.

Comment: @kunjaan, it really would help to know precisely what you mean.  Do you mean that "bookkeeper" becomes "bokeper", or "bokepr", or just a string containing those 6 chars in any order, or something else?

Answer (score 5):

Use `indexOf` and `delete` methods in `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Wouldn't StringBuilder use extra memory, since you are duplicating the string, making it mutable?

Comment: The purpose of the StringBuilder object is to carry out these operations without requiring new immutable copies of the string.

Answer (score 1):

Since a string is immutable you're not going to be able to alter it.  Hence, the new version of the string without the duplicate character will consume memory.  If you give more details behind the purpose and rationale of your request someone might be able to offer a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

Because strings are immutable in Java, you will need **at least** one copy no matter what. Ans the best way you should bet on is to use character array and System.arraycopy. Another alternatives are StringBuilder/StringBuffer and [CharBuffer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/CharBuffer.html). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable, so the reality of it is that you will need to allocate additional memory.

Since you say fastest, I assume you won't consider a 2 pass algorithm.  You can go with StringBuilder but that will allocate your original string length + 16, and, when you call getString() you will again be allocating memory in String constructor.

If you don't mind having a 2 pass algorithm, you are looking at 2 allocation of a char[] (of final length of cleaned up string).  Use a StringBuilder and you are looking at 2*len + 16, but it would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a **StringBuilder**.  However, here's a method which you can shoot yourself in the foot with:

```
    String s = "bookkeepers";
    Class<?> c = String.class;
    Field field = c.getDeclaredField("value");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    char[] value = (char[]) field.get(s);
    // remove duplicate characters
    char last = 0;
    int len = 0;
    int writePtr = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        value[writePtr] = value[i];
        if (value[i] != last) {
            writePtr++;
            last = value[i];
            len++;
        }
    }
    Field count = c.getDeclaredField("count");
    count.setAccessible(true);
    count.set(s, len);

    System.out.println(s);
```

Output `bokepers`